# SkipListener does not work with AsyncItemProcessor, AsyncItemWriter in spring boot 3 & java 17

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm writing a Spring Boot application that starts up, read->process->write millions file records into a new file. I'm attempting to use Spring Batch for this and using AsyncItemProcessor, AsyncItemWriter for faster execution, but I'm running into trouble implementing fault tolerance.

In my processor I am running a DB query to fetch some additional data for input records before writing to new file. I also want to write a error file where records is not present in DB. To achieve this, I've attempted to use Spring Batch's SkipListener interface. But I don't see anything in SkipListener log even my query return EmptyResultDataAccessException

Everything works perfect with normal processor and writer but not with Async one. Have I misconfigured something? Is there any other way to write error records to different file if exception occurs?

Here's what I have tried

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class BatchJob {

    @Scheduled(cron = "${job.batch.cron}")
    public void launchJob() throws Exception {
        Date date = new Date();
        log.debug("In BatchJob - launchJob()");
        log.info("Scheduler starts at [{}]", date);
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job(jobRepository, transactionManager), new JobParametersBuilder().addDate("launchDate", date)
                .toJobParameters());
        log.info("Batch job ends with status as [{}]", jobExecution.getStatus());
        log.info("Scheduler ends at [{}]", new Date());
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        return new JobBuilder("myJob", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(jobListener)
                .start(fileValidationStep(jobRepository, transactionManager)).on("FILE_NOT_FOUND").end()
                .from(fileValidationStep(jobRepository, transactionManager)).on("FILE_FOUND").to(recordProcessingStep(jobRepository, transactionManager))
                .from(recordProcessingStep(jobRepository, transactionManager)).on("*").to(fileMoveStep(jobRepository, transactionManager)).end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step fileValidationStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        return new StepBuilder(fileValidationStep, jobRepository)
                .tasklet(new Tasklet() {
                    @Override
                    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    }
                }, transactionManager)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step fileMoveStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        return new StepBuilder("fileMoveStep", jobRepository)
                .tasklet(new Tasklet() {
                    @Override
                    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    }
                }, transactionManager)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected Step recordProcessingStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        SimpleStepBuilder stepBuilder = new StepBuilder("recordProcessingStep", jobRepository)
                .<DemoRecord, Future<DemoRecord>>chunk(chunkSize, transactionManager)
                .reader(recordReader())
                .processor(asyncProcessor())
                .writer(asyncWriter())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skipLimit(skipLimit)
                .skip(Exception.class)
                .noSkip(FileNotFoundException.class)
                .listener(skipListener)
                .stream(subscriberWriter())
                .stream(dummyWriter());
        stepBuilder.listener(chunkListener);
        return stepBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<DemoRecord> recordReader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<DemoRecord> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(inputFilePath);
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<DemoRecord>() {{
            setLineTokenizer(new FixedLengthTokenizer() {{
                setNames(inputColumnNames).toArray(new String[0]));
                setColumns(inputColumnRanges);
            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>() {
                {
                    setTargetType(DemoRecord.class);
                }
            });
        }});
        reader.setLinesToSkip(linesToSkip);
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<DemoRecord> classifierCompositeItemWriter() throws Exception {
        ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<DemoRecord> compositeItemWriter = new ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<>();
        compositeItemWriter.setClassifier(new DemoDataClassifier(subscriberWriter(), dummyWriter()));
        return compositeItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemWriter<DemoRecord> subscriberWriter() {
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<DemoRecord> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(outputColumnNames);
        fieldExtractor.afterPropertiesSet();

        FormatterLineAggregator<DemoRecord> lineAggregator = new FormatterLineAggregator<>();
        lineAggregator.setFormat(outputColumnFormats);
        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<DemoRecord>()
                .name("subscriberWriter")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(targetDir)
                        .lineAggregator(lineAggregator)
                        .shouldDeleteIfExists(true)
                        .shouldDeleteIfEmpty(true)
                        .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemWriter<DemoRecord> dummyWriter() {
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<DemoRecord> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(outputColumnNames);
        fieldExtractor.afterPropertiesSet();

        FormatterLineAggregator<DemoRecord> lineAggregator = new FormatterLineAggregator<>();
        lineAggregator.setFormat(outputColumnFormats);
        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<DemoRecord>()
                .name("dummyWriter")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(target)
                        .lineAggregator(lineAggregator)
                        .shouldDeleteIfExists(true)
                        .shouldDeleteIfEmpty(true)
                        .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public AsyncItemProcessor<DemoRecord, DemoRecord> asyncProcessor() {
        AsyncItemProcessor<DemoRecord, DemoRecord> asyncItemProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor<>();
        asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(recordProcessor);
        asyncItemProcessor.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        return asyncItemProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public AsyncItemWriter<DemoRecord> asyncWriter() throws Exception {
        AsyncItemWriter<DemoRecord> asyncItemWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
        asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(classifierCompositeItemWriter());
        return asyncItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(64);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(64);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(64);
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MultiThreaded-");
        return executor;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are mixing two concurrency approaches: multi-threaded steps (by setting a task executor on the step) and async item processing (by using `AsyncItemProcessor`/`AsyncItemWriter`). Please remove the task executor from the step and share your feedback if the skip listener is invoked as expected with just an async processor/writer.

Comment: Remains same even I remove taskExecutor.   PS: Updated the code snippet as well

Answer (score 0):

Some fault-tolerance features are not compatible with async processing, including the skip functionality. This is mentioned in the javadoc of the [AsyncItemProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/integration/async/AsyncItemProcessor.html):

```
Because the Future is typically unwrapped in the ItemWriter, there are lifecycle
and stats limitations (since the framework doesn't know what the result of the 
processor is). While not an exhaustive list, things like StepExecution.getFilterCount()
will not reflect the number of filtered items and 
ItemProcessListener.onProcessError(Object, Exception) will not be called.
```